# Loud squeaking - stops when braking

Tags: noise

Got the car serviced last Thursday. Since then, when I drive around I hear a loud tweeting noise from the front driver side, if I turn the wheel left and right it goes louder and quieter, if I apply the brake it stops
any ideas ?

Comment: What did they do in the service? Did they work on the brakes?

Answer (score 6):

From your description, it seems the brake "squealer" has started to rub against the brake rotor. This is a tab which is attached to one of the two disk brake pads. When the friction material gets worn to a point, it makes contact with the rotor and starts making noise. The tell tale is, when you engage the brakes, the noise goes away.

Have your brakes checked.

Comment: These are new pads though.  Only been on one month

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar symptoms when a small piece of gravel was stuck between the backing plate and the caliper. Another reason could be a slightly bent backing plate.